# Not able to edit robots.txt

Tags: magento-1.9

My site is in magento1. When i test my site in google's mobile compatibility testing tool it gives below error.

Page cannot be reached
This could be because the page is unavailable or blocked by robots.txt

I am also not able to edit robots.txt

Comment: Set your admin config `System --> Configuration ---> Design` to `INDEX, FOLLOW`

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Check file permissions of robots.txt using ftp